# Dart - Use integer in a map

Tags: flutter, dart

Using [carousel_slider 1.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) I need to provide a map to define the amount of items in the slider.

Im able to find the amount of items coming from an API using 'articlesMap' but I need to convert this integer into `List<Map>` as the slider uses the following input:

```
items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {})
```

How would I go about converting this? The amount of items the slider receives isn't static and thus I can't rely on inputting `[1,2,3,4,5]` where I may receive +/- 5 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart provides a generator for lists, which you could use as:

```
items: List<int>.generate(articlesList.length, (i) => i + 1).map...
```

It would probably be simpler to just map you articles list (you don't show where you get the articles):

```
  CarouselSlider(
    height: 400.0,
    items: articlesList
        .map((a) => Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                    child: Text(
                      a.name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
            ))
        .toList(),
  );
```

If the articles are really in a map, you can convert to a list with `.values`